# Where should you put "typedef enum"s in your source?

Tags: c, header-files, code-organization

I'm working on a larger project than I'm used to, and I'm doing my best to keep my code properly structured. I am programming a microcontroller and have some global variables, which as per some advice I read on here are all defined in a "global_variables.h" file which is included anywhere that the global variables are used.

I also put the typedef for the global variables into the "global_variables.h" file.

The problem I am running across is that the file1.c in which I use the global variable has a function1(new_type_t variable) which accepts the new typedef as a parameter. The problem with this is that I have the function1 prototype defined in the header (file1.h), but since the #include "global_variables.h" is located in file1.c, the function prototype in file1.h does not see the typedef.

I feel like this is a common occurrence, but Googling didn't seem to provide too much help. Should I make a separate "global_variables.h" and "global_variables_types.h" and include the .h file in the headers of my other files and the .c in the sources?

Comment: You just need to `#include "global_variables.h"` in file1.h.

Comment: I think the split he's suggesting is somewhat more flexible, since it would result in smaller building blocks, so to speak.

Comment: How large is your project? Overall size is 1KLOC (thousand of source code lines), 10KLOC, 100KLOC???

Comment: Less than 20 files. Small by normal standards but larger than the 3-4 files I'm used to doing.

Comment: But how many source lines of code?? Some people have rather big files (eg 20KLOC in a single `*.c` file), others are dividing their code in many files of less than 100 lines. On Linux you can use `wc -l *.[ch]` or `sloccount` to measure the size of a project source code.

Comment: Probably between 1KLOC and 10KLOC,

Comment: Then you definitely should have only one header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that having a header file `global_variables.h` is sensible.

If your project is a small single-person project (e.g. less than 50KLOC = 50 thousand lines of source code), and you don't intend to make a reusable library, having one single header file for all the project is probably sensible. That header file would declare the global variables, and before them the relevant types. You'll also declare all your functions, and at last define all your inlined functions. You could consider having the inlined functions in a separate header file (including from your main header).

If you intend to make reusable code, make separate headers for separate subsystems of your project. But I don't feel the need to have a header for just all the global variables.

Most importantly, **keep your set of global variables minimal**. You should be able to count global variables with the fingers of a single hand. If you need more than 4 or 5 global variables, consider packing related global variables in a global `struct`. For instance, if the screen size is in global data, don't declare `int screen_width, screen_height;` but rather

```
 struct {
    int width;
    int height;
 } screen;
```

Of course, the true thing depends upon the project, and perhaps upon the build chain. Some proprietary compilers don't really optimize, and might produce bad code if using global structures. If you use a recent GCC (as a cross compiler, preferably on Linux), you don't have that issue, since GCC optimize well. Always enable all warnings on your compiler (e.g. build with `gcc -Wall -g -O2`)

A good advice would be to **study the source code of some *existing* free software** similar to yours.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of important rules for header files that make things go smoothly..\

First off, use header guards so that multiple inclusion doesn't cause problems.

in module.h...

```
  #ifndef MODULE_H
  #define MODULE_H
  ...
  #endif
```

Now, it doesn't matter if you include the same header twice.

The second rule (now you have header guards) is that each .h file should include all others that it needs to compile. When you've done this your code will be more robust in terms of reusing one header in another module, and getting header ordering correct.

```
  #ifndef MODULE_H
  #define MODULE_H

  #include "module2.h"  // we need a type from here.

  void myFunc(Module2Type t); 
  #endif
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to include global_variables.h in file1.h instead of file1.c. Whether that is a good solution or not, depends on your source tree.

Answer (score 1):

A common and flexible approach is to declare the global vars in .h with `extern` linkage. Then define the globals in a .c file of your choice.

Include that .h anywhere you need to reference the globals. Linker will take care of resolving the reference to the respective .obj file.

Indeed the less globals the more sanity in tracking who uses them.